# Custom Field RenderPattern Customization - SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, javascript, custom-field-types, caml, caml-renderpattern

I'm creating a custom field in SP 2007. I need to Get the Custom field value and field properties on Item click, in the list item display view. Also i Need to pass these values to a JavaScript.

So, Customizing the CAML code inside the *RenderPattern* for this. I would like to know how this could be done.

--
I have added the below code to the CAML

```
<RenderPattern Name="DisplayPattern">
  <HTML><![CDATA[</div><br/><br/><div>Name Value:</div><br/>]]></HTML>
  <ScriptQuote>
    <Property Select="Name" HTMLEncode="True" />
  </ScriptQuote>

  <HTML><![CDATA[<div>Custom Property 1 Value</div><br/>]]></HTML>
  <ScriptQuote>  
      <Property Select="MyCustomProperty1" URLEncode="True" />
  </ScriptQuote>
  <HTML><![CDATA[<div>Custom Property 2 Value</div><br/>]]></HTML>
  <ScriptQuote>
      <Property Select="MyCustomProperty2" URLEncode="True" />
  </ScriptQuote>
  <HTML><![CDATA[<div>Description : </div><br/>]]></HTML>
  <ScriptQuote>
    <Property Select="Description" HTMLEncode="True" />
  </ScriptQuote>
  <HTML><![CDATA[<div>Required : </div><br/>]]></HTML>
  <ScriptQuote>
    <Property Select="Required" HTMLEncode="True" />
  </ScriptQuote>
  <Column HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>

</RenderPattern>
```

I get "_x0070_df2" for name.
Just "" for the two of my custom properties.

Whereas for Description I get the value and for Required property i get "FALSE".
Wondering why i didn't get the values set for the custom properties ....

Tried *URLEncode* for the custom properties instead of *HTMLEncode* which had the same result.